# How to find the code of a numbered tree?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, graph-theory

This is from my math book:

> An n-vertex numbered tree is a tree whose vertex set is {1, 2, ..., n} for some n > 2. We define the code of the numbered tree to be a sequence of n-2 integers from 1 to n obtained by the following recursive process:
>
> If there are more than two vertices left, write down the father$^6$ of the largest leaf, delete this leaf, and continue this process on the resulting smaller tree. If there are only two vertices left, then stop - the code is complete.
>
> $^6$The necessarily unique node adjacent to a leaf is called its father.

This is the examples they use:

[image: Trees and their Codes]

Now, what I don't understand is how did they get the codes for the first tree? It says to write down the father of the largest node, so we write down 6, and delete 7. Then in the next iteration, the father of 6 is 5, so we write it down and delete 5. The next largest node again is 6, and the father of 6 is 2, so shouldn't we write down 2 and not 6? I don't understand how they managed to get 2 6s and 2 2s in the code for the first tree.

It makes sense in the 2nd tree because 5 is the largest, and its father is 4, so we write it down. Then the largest is 4, and the father of it is 3, and so on until we get 432. I get that.

What I don't understand is what did they do in the first graph? Shouldn't the answer be 652? 6 is the father of 7, so 7 is deleted. 5 is the father of 6, so 5 is deleted. Then, the father of 6 is 2, so 2 is deleted...?

Comment: 6 is not a leaf after the first deletion.

Comment: I just suddenly realized what a leaf was. I kept thinking of it as a node.

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out because I forgot what a leaf was, and I kept confusing it for a node.

So first, the largest is node 7, and its father is 6. After removing 7, the next largest node that has 1 edge is 4, so the father of 4 is 5. Then, we remove 4. Next, the next largest node that has 1 edge is 5, and its father is 6, so we write down 6 again. After removing 5, the next largest node with 1 edge is 3, so its father is 2. After removing 3, we have 1 as the next largest node with only 1 edge, so its father is 2, and we write it down. The process now ends since 2 nodes are now left, so we have 65622.

Comment: yes, that’s the definition of a leaf.